# Martingale and Absorbing states in a Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, expected-value, conditional-probability, martingales

I have problem with this question. I've already proved a), but I can't get through b). 
Define $ (X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ a Markov Chain with state-space $S = \{0,1, \dots , N \} $ with transition probabilities such that por any state $x$

$$ \mathbb{E} (X_{n+1} | X_n = x) = \sum_{y=0}^{N} y P(x,y) = x$$

Prove:

a) $ (X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is a martingale, and 
b) $0$ and $N$ are absorbing states.

For proving b), I thought of using the martingale property; nonetheless, I did not get anything. Also, I approach by using the Law of total expectation, but I got stuck.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I could solve b). I post my answer for you all.

$\textbf{Answer for a)}$

First, by construction of $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is adapted in the natural filtration, that is $\mathcal{F}_n^X = \sigma( \{ X_0, \dots , X_n \})$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Second, let's see if $X_n \in L^1$. As the stat space is $S = \{0,1, \dots , N\}$ then we obtain the following

$$\mathbb{E} (|X_n|) = \mathbb{E} (X_n) = \sum_{x=0}^{N} x \mathbb{P}(X_n = x) \leq \sum_{x=0}^{N} x = \dfrac{N(N+1)}{2} < + \infty$$

As result, $X_n \in L^1$.

Finally, let's look for the martingale property. We can see that

$$\mathbb{E} (X_{n+1} | \mathcal{F}_n^X) = \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}| X_0,X_1, \dots, X_n)$$

If we consider that $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Markov Chain and analize that for all $x_0,x_1, \dots , x_n$, we can infer that

$$\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}| X_0 = x_0, \dots, X_n = x_n) & = \sum_{y=0}^{N} y \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=y|X_0 = x_0, \dots, X_n = x_n)\\
& = \sum_{y=0}^N y \mathbb{P} ( X_{n+1} = y| X_n = x) \\
& = \mathbb{E} (X_{n+1} | X_n = x_n) = x_n
\end{split}$$

We get the last equality by hypothesis. Then, we conclude that

$$ \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}| X_0 = x_0, \dots, X_n = x_n) = x_n$$

Thus, after generalizing,

$$ \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}| X_0 , \dots, X_n ) = X_n \iff \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}| \mathcal{F}_n^X) = X_n$$

We conclude that $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale.

$\textbf{Answer for b)}$

First, we consider the stat $x=0$. We get that, by hypothesis

$$\sum_{y=0}^N y P(0,y) = 0 \iff  0P(0,0) + \sum_{y=1}^N y P(0,y) = 0 \tag{1}$$

Let's remember that $P(x,y)$ denotes the transition probability from $x$ to $y$ in one step. Now, as $P$ is an estochastic matrix, we know that, for any state $x$

$$
\sum_{y=0}^N P(x,y) = 1 \tag{2}
$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ equations, we get that $P(0,0)=1$.

Second, for the last state $x=N$ we get that

$$
\sum_{y=0}^N y P(N,y) = N \iff \sum_{y=0}^N \frac{y}{N} P(N,y) = 1 \tag{3}
$$

Now, if we combine the equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get that

$$\sum_{y=0}^N \Big( 1 - \frac{y}{N} \Big) P(N,y) = 0$$

$$\sum_{y=1}^N \Big( 1 - \frac{y}{N} \Big) P(N,y) + \Big( 1 - \frac{N}{N} \Big) P(N,N) = 0$$

As a final result $P(N,N) = 1$.

So, we conclude that the absorbing states of the Markov Chain are $x=0,N$.

Answer (score 1):

You have, by specializing to $x=0$,
$$
0=\sum_{y=0}^N yP(0,y).
$$
What conclusion can be drawn from this?

Comment: From there, I can get that $0 P(0,y) + \sum_{y=1}^{N} y P(0,y) = 0$. Now, as $\sum_{y=0}^{N} P(0,y)=1$. As I use both equations, then $P(0,0)=1$. Thank you @John Dawkins I think I can get through por $x=N$.

Comment: Can it be shown that rest all states are transient (except 0 and N)?

Comment: @shsh23: Maybe not. The given hypotheses seem to allow for the situation in which each state is absorbing.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Oh yeah thanks.